# Using AppLocale with LabVIEW

Tags: windows-8.1, uac, labview

I am running LabVIEW 2013 Dev Environment on a Chinese Windows 8 platform. LabVIEW is not a Unicode-base program, and consequently on Asian Windows there are display issues for our interfaces created with US-English character sets. I can fix this problem by setting the language settings for non-unicode programs to English. This works fine, except that all my other non-unicode-based programs are totally illegible.

A quick google search turned up Microsoft's utility for running application with a user-specified code page, [AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13209). The utility is only written to be compatible up to Windows XP. There are two suggested methods I ran accross for installing it: 1. run installer using compatibility settings 2. install using command prompt with admin privileges (apparently it doesn't play well with UAC. You can find one set of instructions [here](http://opcode0x90.wordpress.com/2008/01/09/patch-for-applocale/) for installing AppLocale on Windows with UAC.

Unfortunately, nothing I have tried has been able to get LabVIEW to use the code page I would like it to. When I run LabVIEW through AppLocale and open the user-interface I am concerned about, the characters still do not display properly.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Could there be a fundamental incompatibility with LabVIEW?
Does anyone know of an alternative to AppLocale that might work for me?

Comment: What language of LabVIEW are you using?  Have you looked here: https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-10153

Comment: What kind of English characters are coming illegible under the foreign language version of Windows? The basic Latin characters (A-Z,a-z,0-9, etc) should be coming up fine.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to Applocale on windows 8 is [Locale Emulator](https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator) created by xupefei. You will have to have visual studio to build the project.

Make sure that your region settings are set to an english speaking region such as the united states of america. You can check this under
control panel >> clock, language, and region >> region settings

Additionally ensure that you have the language packs installed for the character sets used by LabVIEW. You can check which language packs you have installed under control panel >> clock, language, and region >> language
You will want to have installed support for complex languages

If none of these things work I would try upgrading to windows 10 as it has much better language support